qtwebengine compilation in BLFS 12 project with weak PC
I'm trying to build the QtWebEngine-5.15.17 from BLFS 12 project, but facing failures.
My PC is pretty old with weak 2 core proc:
Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B960 @ 2.20GHz
my RAM size is 5883136 kB
I tried to use make arguments to reduce the parallelism like NINJAJOBS=1, MAKEOPTS="-j1" and make -j1. No luck:((
Is there any way to successfully finish the build on such kind of PC?
I tried to use make arguments to reduce the parallelism like NINJAJOBS=1, MAKEOPTS="-j1" and make -j1.
Need to find a way to build the package.
